# Reading a comma delimited CSV that contains currency

Tags: c#, csv, streamreader

In the following that reads from a comma delimited CSV file.

The currency field  which is the third field in each line [2] is the problem.
I need to split the fields at the comma but the currency field may sometimes be large and also have them.

*How can you split a comma separated csv file that contains currency.??*

The csv is always consistent 5 fields on each line.

The first line in the example below works but the second line would cause the issue.

3,09:29 pm,€20.00,Test,Test

1,02:55 am,€10,000.00,Test,Test

```
StreamReader fileIn = new StreamReader(path);
        //Read the file
        while (!fileIn.EndOfStream)
        {
           String line = fileIn.ReadLine();
           String[] pieces = line.Split(',');

           csvComplete cEve = new csvComplete (pieces[0], pieces[1], pieces[2], pieces[3], pieces[4]);// assign to class cEve
           entries.Add(cEve);

        }
```

Any links or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: if the fields are quote-delimited (`"abc", "d,e,f", "ghi"`) TextFieldParser and other tools will handle it, but `String.Split` will not.  If you are making the CSV consider using semi colons as the field seperator

Comment: Sorry no, I have no control over the csv, I was thinking along the lines of after the second comma ignore the rest untill i reach "Something" but the next something can only be a comma.. I'm a bit lost.

Comment: You could parse it backwards for the last two fields, trim off the first two fields, and assume the remaining text is the currency field.

Comment: Interesting problem. This CSV file is actually invalid because the field with the comma inside is supposed to be escaped with double-quotes.

Comment: Hi gordy i like that idea,I'm not sure it would be reliable enough in this case. But it will be used in others Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hack:

```
//Read the file
while (!fileIn.EndOfStream)
{
   String line = fileIn.ReadLine();
   String[] pieces = line.Split(',');
   if(pieces.length > 5){
       String[] newPieces = new String[5];
       newPieces[0] = pieces[0];
       newPieces[1] = pieces[1];
       String currency = "";
       for(int i = 2; i < pieces.length - 2; i++){
           if(i == pieces.length -3)
               currency += pieces[i];
           else{
               currency += pieces[i] + ",";
           }
       }
       newPieces[2] = currency;
       newPieces[3] = pieces[pieces.length-2];
       newPieces[4] = pieces[pieces.length-1];
       csvComplete cEve = new csvComplete (newPieces[0], newPieces[1], newPieces[2], newPieces[3], newPieces[4]);// assign to class cEve
       entries.Add(cEve);
   }
   else{
       csvComplete cEve = new csvComplete (pieces[0], pieces[1], pieces[2], pieces[3], pieces[4]);// assign to class cEve
       entries.Add(cEve);
   }

 }
```

This should account for bigger currencies (trillions of euros will have more commas).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem before and I turned to the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser`. In your case, try this:

```
using(TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(new StreamReader(path)){
    parser.Delimiters = new string [] {","};

    while(true){
        String[] pieces = parser.ReadFields();
        if(pieces == null)
            break;

        csvComplete cEve = new csvComplete (pieces[0], pieces[1], pieces[2], pieces[3], pieces[4]);// assign to class cEve
        entries.Add(cEve);
    }
}
```

Additional information can be found [here](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=textfieldparser%20vb.net).

Comment: I can try it thanks, but first I'm just wondering how will the textfieldparser tell the difference in the currency field?? I will read up on it but it seems that example will have the same result??

Comment: In my situation, one of my fields started showing multiple IP addresses (comma delimited) where it used to show a phone number. Changing my `String.Split()` way of handling the csv to this solved the issue.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm going to try to stay out of the VB for the time being tho, Thanks a mill for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Brute force:

```
        StreamReader fileIn = new StreamReader(path);
        //Read the file
        while (!fileIn.EndOfStream)
        {
           String line = fileIn.ReadLine();
           String[] pieces = line.Split(',');
           if (pieces.Length == 5)
           {
               // Exactly 5 fields.   
               csvComplete cEve = new csvComplete (pieces[0], pieces[1], pieces[2], pieces[3], pieces[4]);// assign to class cEve
           }
           else if (pieces.Length == 6)
           {
               // Exactly 6 fields. We'll assume fields 1 and 2 should combine for currency string.
               csvComplete cEve = new csvComplete (pieces[0], pieces[1] + "," + pieces[2], pieces[3], pieces[4], pieces[5], pieces[6]);// assign to class cEve
           }
           else
           {
               // ?
           }
           entries.Add(cEve);

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

**If line length is dynamic**

My solution to this problem is to implement logic that looks for the Euro symbol "€" in one member of the array and a radix "." in the subsequent member. If this condition is met, then you can assume you have encountered the special situation you have mentioned.

**If we know how many fields should be on a line**

Alternatively, if you know that you should always have the same number of members in each array (fields on each line of the CSV), then you logic becomes simpler. Just look for an array with one member too many.

Taking your example, we make the assumption that each array should have precisely five members:

0: Index / ID number

1: Meridian time value

2: EUR currency amount

3: Test data 1

4: Test data 2

We can now look for an array with six members and apply our business logic:

```
String line = fileIn.ReadLine();
String[] pieces = line.Split(',');

if( pieces.Length == 6 ) 
{
    pieces[2] = String.Concat(pieces[2], pieces[3]);
    pieces[3] = pieces[4];
    pieces[4] = pieces[5];
}    

csvComplete cEve = new csvComplete (pieces[0], pieces[1], pieces[2], pieces[3], pieces[4]);// assign to class cEve
entries.Add(cEve);
```

Comment: Thanks I think that will do I will just add a few more scenarios to it and it will be perfect for what i need thanks a mill..Mark and everyone else for your help

Answer (score 0):

## Light weight solution

> Has you can see I convert the comma inside the quotes in another character. And works for all the fields with the same case inside the string. You can put this snippet inside a method for reusability.

**Sample string:**
40,3063,16,32,36,37,41,56,5,***"$30,600,000.00"***,12/4/2017

```
                string sRead = sr.ReadLine();
                char[] srcTemp = sRead.ToCharArray();
                for (int i = 0; i < srcTemp.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    if ((int)srcTemp[i] == 34)
                    {
                        int yCharnichart = 0;
                        for (int c = i + 1; c < srcTemp.Length - 1; c++)
                        {
                            if ((int)srcTemp[c] == 34) break;
                            if ((int)srcTemp[c] == 44) srcTemp[c] = (char)182;
                            yCharnichart++;
                        }
                        i += yCharnichart + 1;
                    }
                }
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append(srcTemp);
```

> **Result:** 40,3063,16,32,36,37,41,56,5,***"$30¶600¶000.00"***,12/4/2017

**Finally:**  Just replace your character of choice again for a comma again

```
BOLSA = arRead[9].Replace((char)182, (char)44)
```